# Compare same dates in different columns and copy associated values

Tags: date, google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I have a two sheets within one document. On one sheet users enter data like this:

**Date** **Value**

(below these columns they enter dates and values.)

In the other sheet I have dates day by day. My plan was get the value from user sheet and pull it to the other sheet next to the cell with the same date.

How do I do this, with functions or a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user's sheet is called `Users` and say has `1/1/15` in A2 and `1` in B2 and your other has `1/1/15` in C3 and you want the `1` to copy into D3 then in D3:

```
=vlookup(C3,Users!A:B,2,0)
```